# How can I hide my div using jQuery, and then showing it again by pressing a different div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want to do is:

Make my div hidden when the page loads, and then when you click a different div it will show. My limited knowledge doesn't really allow me to make this happen. What am I doing wrong?

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#trojkat2').click(function(){
        $('#login').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

"trojkat2" is the div I want to click to make "login" appear.

HTML:

```
 <div class="kwadrat2">
    <div class="trojkat2">
    <div class="trojkat_bg2"></div>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="login">
<img style="height: 550px; width: 280px; border-radius: 10px;" src="buymenu.jpg">
</div>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: there is no element in your example with id = trojkat2 or id = login. Atleast your first statement should be $('.trojkat2').click instead of $('#trojkat2').click

Comment: use toogle may be this can help u

Comment: Hide the element with CSS, and then replace `hide()` with `show()`, and note that your elements have classes

Comment: @DinoMyte Thank you, you just solved the problem! I'm very thankful :)

Comment: If it's already answered... why do people keep posting answers?

Comment: update answer as your updated html.

Comment: @AndrueAnderson I think is because they are typing.. after post then found other answer.. see the gap is less than one min..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, hide your #login div when document ready by .hide() function, after click $(.trojkat2), use show() to make #login appear, by the way class selector is . instead of #

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.login').hide();
    $('.trojkat2').click(function(){
        $('.login').show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kwadrat2">
<div class="trojkat2">click here
<div class="trojkat_bg2"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="login">
<img style="height: 550px; width: 280px; border-radius: 10px;" src="buymenu.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.trojkat2').click(function() {
    $('.login').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't have an element with id = trojkat2 so your selector $("#trojkat2") won't work. Same is for #login. Instead you need to change it to a class selector :

```
$('.trojkat2').click(function(){
        $('.login').hide();
    });
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/nrNX8/529/

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML code, you created classes called login and trojkat2. However, in your jQuery, you are telling it to call the IDs called login and trojkat2. Classes are preceded with a "." and IDs are preceded with a "#". Instead, try the following code in your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.trojkat2').click(function(){
        $('.login').hide();
    });
});
```